# CakePHP session and cache handling

Tags: php, session, cakephp, session-cookies, cakephp-2.0

If there are login issues associated with a CakePHP application, is there something specific that one should be looking at ? I understand the permissions should be correctly configured on the tmp directory inside the application directory. The session file is created under `/app/tmp/sessions` but the user is still not logged in. And this seems to be very inconsistent i.e., I can or cannot login as the same user from two different browsers, can login from one browser but cannot login from the other. There isn't a specific pattern at all.

Secondly, every time the latest build is deployed, the application still renders the old cached data. This is inspite of clearing the `app/tmp/cache` directory. As a workaround, I toggle the debug mode in core.php which seems to clear the cache.

Could someone with the knowhow suggest what is the best way to debug the issue, please ?

Thank you

Below is the code for cache and session handling.
I tried changing the session defaults to 'php' from 'cake' and since then its working fine.
But I'm not sure if this can have unforeseen consequences.
So, I would still like to preserve the old code for session handling.

```
 /**
 * Configure the cache used for general framework caching. Path information,
 * object listings, and translation cache files are stored with this configuration.
 */
Cache::config('_cake_core_', array(
'engine' => $engine,
'prefix' => $prefix . 'cake_core_',
'path' => CACHE . 'persistent' . DS,
'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
'duration' => $duration
));

 /**
 * Configure the cache for model and datasource caches. This cache configuration
 * is used to store schema descriptions, and table listings in connections.
 */

Cache::config('_cake_model_', array(
'engine' => $engine,
'prefix' => $prefix . 'cake_model_',
'path' => CACHE . 'models' . DS,
'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
'duration' => $duration
));


Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake',
    'timeout' => 86400, // The session will timeout after 2 hours of inactivity
    'cookieTimeout' => 86400, // The session cookie will live for at most 24 hours, this does not effect session timeouts
    'checkAgent' => false,
    'autoRegenerate' => true,  // causes the session expiration time to reset on each page load
));


Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake',
    'timeout' => 86400,
    'ini' => array(
        'session.cookie_path' => str_replace(str_replace(DS, '/', str_replace(ROOT, '', WWW_ROOT).'index.php'), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])
    )
));
```

The above session handling part has been changed to the below and since then its been fine.

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'timeout' => 86400, // The session will timeout after 2 hours of inactivity
    'cookieTimeout' => 86400, // The session cookie will live for at most 24 hours, this does not effect session timeouts
    'checkAgent' => false,
    'autoRegenerate' => true,  // causes the session expiration time to reset on each page load
));
```

Comment: This seems like two different problems, perhaps with two different solutions. Re logins, you've shown your session settings, but told us nothing at all about what you are using for authentication. Re cache, you haven't indicated anything about how you are caching content; by default, no content is cached, so how you're doing that might well affect the answer here.